# Design Patterns Used in CakePHP

Tags: oop, design-patterns, cakephp

**My Question:
*What are some good examples of design patterns used in CakePHP?***

**Why Use CakePHP As My Context**
I've been using CakePHP for about a year so I think it's easier for me to think in that context. CakePHP is also rich in design pattern use (I'm confident of that)--I just don't know what patterns are being used other than a few obvious ones.

**Example Books I've been Reading On the Subject:**
I'm reading the following books which all cover design patterns to one extent or another; unfortunately they mostly use Java and C++ code examples which makes it harder for me to get a grip on the design patterns on a practical level (I'm a PHP developer so its hard for me to absorb it): 
*"Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture"*, by Martin Fowler
*"Head First Design Patterns"*, by Gang of Four (Eric Freeman, Elisabeth Freeman, Kathy Sierra & Bert Bates) (2004)
*"Design Patterns: Elements of Resuable Object Oriented Software)"*, by Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson, John Vlissides)

**Examples of Patterns I Can Observe in CakePHP**
-I'm guessing the config file uses something akin to the *factory* pattern
-maybe $this->params is using something related to the *observer* pattern? I'm not sure on that...
-MVC (obvious! since Cake PHP uses the MVC file structure)
-ORM (another very obvious one)
-Maybe the HTML helper is using the decorator pattern?

**Summary**
I don't expect anyone to go down the line and identify all the patterns used in CakePHP--I'm just looking for a few examples of design patterns that should be obvious that I'm missing.

Comment: IMHO Cake is unfortunately using too little patterns. More OO/encapsulation/dependency injection/loose coupling/duck typing would help a lot in developing more complex applications. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: ActiveRecord, Association Data Mapping, Front Controller and MVC.

Comment: I'm starting to see how some designs patterns overlap. For example the "domain model" design pattern overlaps the "M" in MVC. The "simple domain model" pattern has one database table for each domain object. This overlaps the CakePHP standard pattern for the "M" or Model in MVC (where we effectively have one "M-Model" class per database table). Another example of overlap is the "front controller" pattern where the "C" (controller) in CakePHP also acts as a "transaction script" (since cake has $this->request which handles $_get/$_post/ and $_request...)

Comment: Was about to ask this same question myself. Excellent! Have posted this in the CakePHP community in G+. https://plus.google.com/111509997047726623122/posts/QQSPgcDTYqd Hopefully we can get more attention to this question.

Comment: You mentioned you purchased the Head First Design Patterns book. I think Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture by Martin Fowler and Design Patterns: Elements of Reuseable Object Oriented Software are also great books. Also, here's an observation I have made (having asked this question over a year ago, I have had a lot of time to think about this....). Most frameworks have a request object, including CakePHP -- this could be considered an observer type pattern... Most objects are built with a factory pattern, e.g. The view factory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One that comes to mind is the concept of [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin). Not exactly a pattern but actually a language feature available in some languages (ie. modules in Ruby) but not in others (ie. Java). It will be coming to PHP when 5.4 goes stable and we get [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), but CakePHP's model behaviours are a good example of mimicking this kind of multiple inheritance where it normally isn't possible.

```
class Post extends AppModel { // we can only inherit from one class

    public $actsAs = array('This', 'That', 'Other'); // but we can do this instead

}
```

Comment: Is this not a limitation of CakePHP, but rather PHP itself as the programming language?

Comment: Indeed, but CakePHP has made the lack of this language feature a non-issue by allowing us to easily do this in our MVC apps back as far as PHP 4. Worth noting, it's not just behaviors that feel like mixins/traits.. but also controller's components, view's helpers and shell's tasks.

Comment: Your point about mixins / multiple inheritance is definitely worth mention. I didn't realize PHP 5.4 was going to include mixins--that's good news.

Comment: @deizel, I misread your answer.  The last sentence basically cleared up what I as thinking.  I didn't absorb that the first time I read your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Software design patterns (like a RoR):

- Convention over configuration: all configuration files from Configure
- Model-View-Controller: folders: Model, Controller, View, etc
- ActiveRecord, Association Data Mapping: database mapping
- Front Controller: main entry point (index.php)

**Found in the comments:**

Creational patterns:

- Singleton -- find by "getInstance, singleton"
- Factory -- find by "factory"
- Builder -- find by "builder"

Structural patterns:

- Adapter -- find by "adapter"
- Front controller (.htaccess, include)

Behavioral patterns:

- Strategy -- find by "strategy"

View:

- Two-step-view pattern -- "two-step-view"